# How to stop X server in Kubuntu 15.04?

Tags: xorg, kill

In Kubuntu 14.04 and 14.10 I stop the X server with

```
sudo /etc/init.d/lightdm stop
```

but it don't works anymore. How to stop it, to install a graphic driver ?

Comment: I have installed my driver with the recovery mode -> network + root command

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found the command, because now the graphic manager is not Lightdm or KDM anymore. 
The new graphic manager is SDDM and the command to stop it is:

```
sudo systemctl stop sddm.service
```

Comment: I do not see an SDDM service on my machine. I have 16.10

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
sudo service sddm stop
```

(this worked better than the systemctl command for me - no freeze).